# Why do Windows Explorer icons flicker/refresh when opening Chrome or Brave?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, chromium, brave

Every time I open the very first instance of Chrome or Brave, I notice that my desktop icons all flicker/refresh. It does not do this on subsequent instances. If I close all instances, it will do it again on the first.

I just now noticed something else. It does it with Explorer views as well, but only for files/folders that are attributed as encrypted. This means that, if I have a folder full of folders and files, opening the initial instance of either browser will cause the encrypted ones to flicker in addition to my desktop icons.

Since Chrome and Brave are both built off Chromium, it seems this could be due to something in the underlying code base. Still, I'd like to know if anyone else experiences this and has an explanation as to what causes it and if there is a way to prevent it from happening.

Note: There are several other questions out there on the internet about this, but the threads are just full of people saying, "I have this problem, too. Anyone find a solution?" without any solutions.

Comment: Try [Disable Hardware Acceleration In Chrome](https://www.technize.net/google-chrome-disable-hardware-acceleration/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Nope, still flickers when I disable this setting in Chrome and Brave. Out of curiosity, what brought you to recommend this as a solution?

Comment: It has solved other bizarre display problems when using Chrome, eg [Text and certain images changing colors, becoming distorted, or disappearing entirely](//superuser.com/q/1372565)